# How to store value in variables within a loop and run in other loop

Tags: python

```
Min = 0
Sec = 0
if messages.content.startswith('y'):
    await messages.channel.send("Start Counting. Wish you have a nice mood to learn!")
    time.sleep(1)
    await messages.channel.send("If you want to stop this timer you can type 'Stop',thank you.")
    timeLoop = True
    while timeLoop:
        Sec += 1
        await messages.channel.send(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
        time.sleep(1)
        if Sec == 60:
            Sec = 0
            Min += 1
            await messages.channel.send(str(Min) + " Minute")
if messages.content.startswith('check'):
    await messages.channel.send(str(Min) + str(Sec))
```

I want to ask about that I want to show the value of Min and Sec from first if statement to second if statement . But when I run check i always shows me 0Min and 0Sec although the timer is running.
Is there any solution so that the value of this two variables could have store in whole of the program so that my second if statement could have print out values.

Comment: Please format your post better. I think you meant to put it in a code block but put it in quotes.

Comment: How can both `if` statements be true for the same message?

Comment: Don't reset `Min` and `Sec` to 0 each time you process a message.

Comment: How do you get out of the `while timeLoop:` loop? You never set it to `False`.

Comment: @Barmar This is not all of my program I have another if statement to get out the timeLoop

Comment: @Barmar I'm just a begginer and really sucks since I am a self taught learner, i do know that don' reset **Min** and **Sec** to 0 but what should I edit I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loops, when referring to Min and Max, it is creating a new variable. To make it use the already-made variable outside the loop do this:

Before referring to a variable inside a loop you have to make it global like this:

```
global Min, Max
```